# Pentaho Geokettle and Geospatial Analysis Tutorials/EBooks

Tags: geospatial, analysis, pentaho, geo, kettle

I'm looking for good resources to refer to, when configuring geokettle. The docs folder in the installation does not contain a user guide. I have googled for tutorials to no avail. Searching community.pentaho.com does not seem to yield any useful results. The samples folder in the installation contains some examples but I haven't quite found what I am looking for:
For example, pulling data from a database and have it show on a map.

If on the other hand, it is better to use a separate geospatial analysis tool with the community edition of pentaho and integrate to the BI Server, your suggestions are also welcome.

Any form of reference will be accepted.

Rumbi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know for sure but have you tried the forum?

http://www.spatialytics.com/forum/

Also ask them on twitter perhaps: @FORUM_GeoBI